# Issue with custom renderer and adding icons to ToolbarItems/NavigationItem with Xamarin Forms

Tags: ios, xaml, xamarin.ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

**TLDR: When adding an icon property to the ToolbarItem, the custom renderer does not work. The NavigationController.TopViewController.NavigationItem Title is not set in this case**

I am working on implementing a new app using Xamarin Forms, and have run into an issue that can not figure out. First I am trying to build a custom iOS navigation tool bar for this app, I want to add some items to the leftBarItems and remove others. This custom navigation bar will be present on all pages except the masterDetailPage (the first view).  I have got most of the functionality working, however if I add the Icon property to the ToolBarItem, my custom renderer breaks. Here is the renderer:

```cs
[assembly:ExportRenderer(typeof(SecondView),typeof(MainViewModelPageRenderer))]

namespace XLabsTest.iOS
{
   class MainViewModelPageRenderer : PageRenderer
   {                
      public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
      {
         base.ViewWillAppear(animated);

         var itemsInfo = (this.Element as ContentPage).ToolbarItems;

         var navigationItem = 
                this.NavigationController.TopViewController.NavigationItem;
         var leftNativeButtons = (navigationItem.LeftBarButtonItems 
                                 ?? new UIBarButtonItem[] { }).ToList();
         var rightNativeButtons = (navigationItem.RightBarButtonItems 
                                 ?? new UIBarButtonItem[] { }).ToList();
         var tempNativeButtons = (new UIBarButtonItem[] {}).ToList() ;
         rightNativeButtons.ForEach(nativeItem =>
         {
            if (nativeItem.Title != "ItemSetinDetailsPage")
            {    
               var info = GetButtonInfo(itemsInfo, nativeItem.Title);

               if (info.Priority == 0)
               {
                  tempNativeButtons.Add(nativeItem);
                  leftNativeButtons.Add(nativeItem);
               }
            }
          });

          tempNativeButtons.ForEach(nativeItem =>
          {
              rightNativeButtons.Remove(nativeItem);
          });

          navigationItem.RightBarButtonItems = rightNativeButtons.ToArray();
          navigationItem.LeftBarButtonItems = leftNativeButtons.ToArray();
      }

      private ToolbarItem GetButtonInfo(IList<ToolbarItem> items, string name)
      {
          if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name) || items == null)
              return null;
          return items.ToList()
                      .Where(itemData => name.Equals(itemData.Name))
                      .FirstOrDefault();
     }
  }
}
```

I am using xaml for some of the views, here is the code where the items are added:

```
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
  <ToolbarItem Name="Menu" Command="{Binding NavigateMenuCommand}" 
        Order="Primary" Priority="0"/>
  <ToolbarItem Name="Back" Command="{Binding NavigateBackCommand}" 
        Order="Primary" Priority="0" />
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
```

the above code works fine, however if i add this:

```
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
   <ToolbarItem Name="Menu" Command="{Binding NavigateMenuCommand}" 
        Order="Primary" Priority="0" Icon="icon.png" />
   <ToolbarItem Name="Back" Command="{Binding NavigateBackCommand}" 
        Order="Primary" Priority="0" />
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
```

the renderer no longer works. I have narrowed down the issue to when the Icon property is present the nativeItem.Title is null and is not set in the NavigationController.TopViewController.NavigationItem. This will cause my app to throw an error.

I believe this is a bug in the Xamarin code, thus I am looking for a possible work around or any fixes for this issue. I am using the current versions Xamarin and Xamairn.forms.

Comment: looks like a xamarin support question

Comment: I have already contacted Xamarin support, I was just hoping someone else had encountered the issue and found a fix.

Comment: there are lots of rough edges still in XF, I hope they clean it up soon. let us know if there's a solution

Comment: This was a bug in the Xamarin code base. Bug tracker for this issue: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=22621

Answer (score 2):

As a workaround to this issue, you could give some really ugly `ToolbarItem.Name`s that contain the desired name and the icon text (if you won't know the icon filename ahead of time) and then you can split the `Name` in the custom renderer and assign your icon there.

In SecondView your `Name` might become:

```
<ToolbarItem Name="Menu_icon.png" Command="{Binding NavigateMenuCommand}" 
    Order="Primary" Priority="0" Icon="" />
}
```

Then in the custom renderer you can just do `ToolbarItem.Name.Split('_')` to get the icon value and assign the icon in the renderer instead.